# Angular material tabs overlap footer in chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-material

Using angular material and it's tab component it seems to overlap the footer - a md-toolbar - when tab content is bigger than window size.
It seems to happen only in chrome, not in firefox.
Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mDvehBML42Ng5M5lFnZ3?p=preview) - and the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link data-require="angular-material@master" data-semver="0.10.1" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.10.1/angular-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.7"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-aria@1.4.0" data-semver="1.4.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-animate@*" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-material@0.10.1" data-semver="0.10.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.10.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" layout="column">
    <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        My favorite dive sites
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <div flex>
      <md-content>
        <md-tabs md-border-bottom md-dynamic-height>
          <md-tab label="tab one">
            <md-content class="md-padding">
              <h1 class="md-display-1">The Title</h1>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
              <p class="md-body-1">
                Just a proposition
              </p>
            </md-content>
          </md-tab>
          <md-tab label="tab two"></md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
      </md-content>

    </div>
    <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        Younderwater, 2015
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
  </body>

</html>
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Any help really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your css on your <div flex> to :

```
flex: 1 0 auto;
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works. The code is mostly taken from "Unraveling Angular Material" (http://www.amazon.com/Unraveling-Angular-Material-Complete-Samples-ebook/dp/B016QTAQIO) but it has this overlapping problem only in chrome, do you think it's a bug?

Comment: Yes this fixed this issue both for safari and chrome

Comment: Great. Happy it worked for you. 'm not sure whether it's a bug or not. perhaps browser support for flex isn't consistent across the board - i dont use it enough to know. But 'flex' is shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink, and flex-basis, so perhaps it is safest to define all three properties when using it.